# Oracle Group by column inside subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm working with a query in oracle, the query is returning the values properly. this is the query.

```
select max(ids) as IDTRX, monto, saldo, DE31, thekey, tipotrx
    from (select t.*,
         t.SID as ids,
         (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(P.P1204, 5, 12))) as monto,
         ((TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(P.P1204, 5, 12)) * (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(t.EXTRA_INFO, 13,2)) - TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(P.P1204, 3,2))))) as saldo,
         (TO_CHAR(t.DATE_TRX, 'YYMMDD') || t.AUTH_CODE || t.TRANSAC_AMOUNT || t.CARD_NUMBER) as thekey,
         t.EXTRA_INFO AS DE31,
         TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(t.EXTRA_INFO, 12, 1)) as tipotrx
         from TBL_TRX t LEFT JOIN TBL_PRS P ON (t.SID = P.TRANSACT) 
         )t
         group by thekey, monto, saldo, DE31, tipotrx
         order by max(ids) desc;
```

it'sworking and displays all the data

[image]

How can i group the results that share the same "tipotrx", in the image is 6, how can i count all the rows that has 6 and group them??

i tried grouping by tipotrx but it shows everything.

Comment: "count all the rows that has 6 and group them"? What is this supposed to mean? If I count all rows with a six, I'll end up with one number. What is there left to group? What do you want the final result to look like?

Comment: With such questions you'll usually get better help, when you include information on the tables. `TBL_TRX` is a transaction probably, but what is `TBL_PRS`? What are their keys?

Comment: The tables look like imported files with embedded information in `EXTRA_INFO` and `P1204`. I suggest you convert these into a proper data model first before querying data.

Comment: those are the names of the data, i know the names are weird, but it is what it is

Comment: No, you are using `SUBSTR` to extract data. This is something you would not do in a properly built database. There would be a column called price, another called amount, not one column where the characters m to n are the amount for instance.

Comment: in an ideal world yes, but i did not create this database mate, i have to work with what they give me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE or subquery:

```
with q as (
      <your query here>
     )
select tiprotx, count(*)
from t
group by tiprotx;
```

Comment: it's working, but i have a question, my query is selecting the max sid for every different "thekey", so do i paste the entire query in the "with q as ()" or just the subquery??

Comment: @Héctor Pérez Silva: Probably your whole query. You want the row counts of your final result, yes? You get these rows with your full query including the `GROUP BY`. If you only included the subquery, you would get much greater row counts, I guess, because those rows aren't aggregated.